# Many "UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds" about bcache at boot time (kernel 6.5.0)

Tags: kernel, btrfs, bcache

I installed a btrfs filesystem relying on two devices (for btrfs raid1) that are  mappers (cryptsetup luksOpen) of bcache devices (NVME + HDD).

This btrfs filesystem seems to work perfectly.

However, at every boot, I have a lot of (section of) messages of this kind:

```
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595579+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042319] ================================================================================
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595580+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042327] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-SXblTa/linux-6.5.0/drivers/md/bcache/bset.c:1098:3
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595580+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042338] index 4 is out of range for type 'btree_iter_set [4]'
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595580+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042344] CPU: 6 PID: 133 Comm: kworker/6:1 Not tainted 6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595581+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042346] Hardware name: ASUS System Product Name/PRIME X670E-PRO WIFI, BIOS 1813 10/13/2023
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595581+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042347] Workqueue: events register_cache_worker [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595581+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042355] Call Trace:
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595581+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042356]  <TASK>
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595582+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042357]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595582+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042359]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595582+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042361]  __ubsan_handle_out_of_bounds+0xc6/0x110
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595582+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042364]  bch_btree_iter_push+0x2d3/0x4f0 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595583+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042373]  bch_btree_node_read_done+0xcb/0x410 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595583+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042382]  bch_btree_node_read+0xf8/0x1e0 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595583+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042391]  ? __pfx_closure_sync_fn+0x10/0x10 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595584+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042400]  bch_btree_node_get.part.0+0x15c/0x330 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595584+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042408]  ? __bch_btree_ptr_invalid+0x66/0xe0 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595584+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042416]  ? __pfx_up_write+0x10/0x10
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595584+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042419]  bch_btree_node_get+0x16/0x30 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595585+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042427]  run_cache_set+0x596/0x850 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595585+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042435]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595586+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042439]  register_cache_set+0x1a2/0x210 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595587+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042448]  register_cache+0x11a/0x1a0 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595587+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042456]  register_cache_worker+0x22/0x80 [bcache]
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595587+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042464]  process_one_work+0x220/0x440
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595587+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042467]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3f0
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595588+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042468]  ? srso_alias_return_thunk+0x5/0x7f
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595588+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042470]  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0xe/0x20
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595588+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042472]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595588+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042474]  kthread+0xef/0x120
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595589+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042476]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595589+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042478]  ret_from_fork+0x44/0x70
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595590+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042480]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595590+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042482]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595590+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042485]  </TASK>
2023-12-19T23:21:41.595590+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.042486] ================================================================================
```

Followed by

```
2023-12-19T23:21:41.598663+01:00 HostName kernel: [    4.091709] bcache: bch_journal_replay() journal replay done, 0 keys in 2 entries, seq 140818
```

Those messages are displayed at boot time, interrupting the nice graphic display so they are maybe very important.

What do you think about that?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today and I went to grub menu and use older kernel version
After that i free some space and check update and reboot and it seems fine with kernel 6.5